# How to increase NCache memory allocation

Tags: memory, configuration, allocation, ncache

From what I know the memory allocation is set when the cache is created:

```
createcache demoCache /s 127.0.0.1 /S 1024
```

Do you know if the memory allocation for NCache can be increased without reinstalling the cache? I need to increase the NCache memory size on production and reinstalling the cache is the last scenario I can do.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a sollution:

1. cache needs to be stopped: stopCache demoCache /s 127.0.0.1
2. open the config file for the server with as admin: C:\Program Files\NCache\config\config.ncconf
3. update the memory allocation according to your needs, *cache-config* node:

> type="heap" cache-size="2048mb"

4. start the cache back.

Comment: Done. Thank you for the tip.